# Is it possible to update tfs metics like code churn, code coverage, last to break the build with Team City?

Tags: tfs, teamcity, tfsbuild

We've been using Team City as our build deployment server. We'd like to now update the metrics in tfs like "Code Churn", "Code Coverage". Is it possible to do this with TeamCity or do we just need to start using the tfs build server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to publish builds results (including metrics) to the TFS server but only when those are collected via MSTest. The `MSTest /publish` command might be helpful here. It looks like publishing custom results like this will be easier in TFS2010 but there are no details as of yet.

Comment: awesome you just gave me the lead I need to research this further, I'd been at a loss as to what to google.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help. Look for TFS Web Services as well. (Build web services).